# Is there any way to keep track of the fork flags in the live network?

Tags: go-ethereum, hardforks, cli, ethernodes

Or in other words, how is the voting going right now. [Ethernodes' crawler](http://ethernodes.org/network/1/nodes) tells me there are 1072 nodes online right now running version 1.4.10 (search for "1.4.10"). I cannot see however whether they have set a support/oppose flag.

Is there any way to see the distribution of said flags in the live network?

Also, are both clients still working on the same chain at this moment (pre-block #1920000)?

Comment: Also wanted to tag this with 1.4.10 but can't due to my rep :-(

Comment: Yeah, all clients are still running to the same chain, and only from dao fork block there will be a fork if some miner choose to not update the client or to oppose the fork. I'm thinking about your first question, I don't think it's straightforward to know that before the daofork block, but I'm noticing this message from some peers " Peer 7d15a619330de0a6 [eth/63]: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping" so I'm digging inside the code to understand that.

Comment: That fork check timeout just means it's communicating with a pre-1.4.10 client who doesn't know about the flags.

Comment: no, it's not that, because I can currently connect to peers with previous clients without problems. For previous clients anyway it's *implicit* they are opposing to the fork, so after block 1920000 who is pro-fork, and have a 1.4.10+ client, will not be able to connect to them anymore. The pro or con fork information is in the return header while two peers are handshaking (see https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2795) but I can't find a way to expose that information easily without modifying the go client.

Answer (score 1):

CodeTract is always running a monitor.

Since we are currently in the progress of forking, I'll share it for future references:

- https://fork.codetract.io/

I do not know of any other methods to natively monitor the fork though.

- https://www.ethernodes.org/network/1 does list client distribution, but the charts are hard to read when it comes to client version details and sorting is also not available, unfortunately.